# Generic SQL that both Access and ODBC/Oracle can understand

Tags: sql, oracle, ms-access, odbc, query-optimization

I have a MS Access query that is based on a linked ODBC table (Oracle).

I'm troubleshooting the poor performance of the query here: [Access not properly translating `TOP` predicate to ODBC/Oracle SQL](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/189441/access-not-properly-translating-top-predicate-to-odbc-oracle-sql).

```
SELECT ri.*
FROM user1_road_insp AS ri
WHERE ri.insp_id = (
                    select 
                        top 1 ri2.insp_id   
                    from 
                        user1_road_insp ri2 
                    where 
                        ri2.road_id = ri.road_id 
                        and year(insp_date) between  [Enter a START year:] and [Enter a END year:]
                    order by 
                        ri2.insp_date desc, 
                        ri2.length desc,
                        ri2.insp_id
                   );
```

The documentation says:

> When you spot a problem, you can try to resolve it by changing the local query. This is often difficult to do successfully, but you may
>   be able to add criteria that are sent to the server, reducing the
>   number of rows retrieved for local processing.
>       In many cases you will find that, despite your best efforts, Office Access still retrieves some entire tables unnecessarily and
>   performs final query processing locally.

However, it's occurred to me that I don't really understand what sort of SQL I should be writing to make both Access and ODBC/Oracle happy.

Should I be writing some sort of ***generic SQL*** that Access can understand in a local query **AND** that can be easily translated to ODBC/Oracle SQL? Is generic SQL a real thing?

Comment: This seems a bit like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me. Problem: Access does weird things when executing queries on an external DB making it slow. Solution: use a pass-through query for any complex query (anything with subqueries, TOP predicates, DISTINCT, multiple JOINs)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*What kind of SQL does the ODBC driver use?* It depends as typically MS Access has three types of external data connections that interfaces with different SQL dialects each with the ODBC API.

1. **Linked tables** that acts like local tables but are ODBC connected data sources and not stored locally. Once they are incorporated in an Access app, these tables can only use MS Access' SQL dialect. They can be joined with local or even other backend tables from other sources.

   Hence, why `TOP` is available in MS Access and not Oracle. You are essentially using Access SQL to manipulate Oracle data. ODBC serves as the origin point of data while Access' Jet/ACE SQL engine does the processing and resultset viewing in cached memory.

   [image: Linked Tables Ribbon Icon]
2. **Pass-through queries** that do not see local tables or anything else in local app's environment. Such queries use the SQL dialect of the connected database here being Oracle.

   Hence, why `TOP` is NOT available in Oracle and double quotes are allowed in column identifiers. Such quoting would fail in MS Access. Essentially, you are using Oracle SQL to manipulate Oracle data in an Access app. You can take the output of the *sqlout.txt* log and run it in a pass-through query ODBC-connected to your Oracle database.

   [image: Pass Through Query Ribbon Icon]
3. **ADO/DAO Recordsets** that are run entirely via code such as VBA and are direct connections to data sources and uses the connecting database's dialect.

   Here, you using Oracle SQL to manipulate Oracle data in an Access app via the ODBC API.

   [image: ADO VBA Reference]

In each one of these types, you will have to connect to a backend ODBC data source. You do not even need to use the GUI but can use Access' object library to create linked tables (see [DoCmd.TransferDatabase](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/access-vba/articles/docmd-transferdatabase-method-access)) and pass through querydefs (see [QueryDef.Connect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff845479.aspx) or [.Execute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff821728.aspx%5D)).

I suspect the *sqlout.txt* log you see are translations of the ODBC calls to its native dialect.

Comment: Simply `MAX` is an aggregate query while `TOP` is not. Hence different query plans.

Comment: @Wilson - The SQL grammar for ODBC is described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/reference/appendixes/appendix-c-sql-grammar).

Comment: @Wilson ... ODBC drivers are softwares developed by companies (Oracle/Microsoft/IBM) or open-source communities (Postgres/MySQL/SQLite) to connect their data sources to Windows apps. No two drivers are the same. GordThompon's link shows the minimum standard based on ANSI-92 SQL. Practically all RDBMS's are ANSI-plus.

Comment: The *native dialect* would be the connected database. Check the specific driver documentation to see what is available or not. Very new/complex methods may not be available.

Comment: You can delete your own question at any time regardless of moderator. However, the community did show its support by upvoting our answers and your question. So this post does have value. Also, future readers can gain from learning Access' external database interfaces. Consider asking a new question with better precision. But again all your choice!

Answer (score 1):

To build on @Parfait's point #1:

From *[Microsoft Access Developer's Guide to SQL Server](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0672319446)* by Mary Chipman and Andy Baron:

**Optimizing Access Queries:**

There's a common misconception that the Jet engine always retrieves all the data in **linked** SQL Server **tables** and then processes the data locally. This is not usually true. Jet is perfectly capable of sending efficient queries to SQL Server over ODBC and retrieving only the rows required. However, in some cases, Jet will in fact be forced to fetch all the data in certain tables first and then process it. You should be aware of when you are forcing Jet to do this and be sure that it is justified. The following are some general guidelines to follow when creating your Access queries:

- Using expressions that can't be evaluated by the server will cause Jet to retrieve all the data required to evaluate those expressions locally. The impact of using Access-specific expressions, such as domain aggregate functions, Access financial functions, or custom VBA functions will vary depending on where in your query the expressions are used. Using such an expression in the SELECT clause will usually not cause a problem because no extra data will be returned. However, if the expression is in the WHERE clause, that criterion cannot be applied on the server, and all the data evaluated by the expression will have to be returned.
- With multiple criteria, as many as possible will be processed on the server. This means that even if you use criteria that you know include functions that will need to be processed by Jet, adding other criteria that can be handled by the server will reduce the number of records that Jet has to process. Adding criteria on indexed columns is especially helpful.
- Query syntax that includes an Access-specific extension to SQL, not supported by the ODBC driver, may force processing to be done on the client by Access. For example, **even though SELECT TOP 5 PERCENT is now supported by SQL Server, it is not supported by the ODBC driver. If you use that syntax in an Access query, Jet will need to retrieve all the records and calculate which ones are in the top 5 percent.** On the other hand, even though crosstab queries are specific to Access, Jet will translate them into simple GROUP BY queries and fetch just the required data in one trip to the server unless problematic criteria is used.
- Heterogeneous joins between local and remote tables or between remote tables that are in different data sources will, of course, have to be processed by Jet after the source data is retrieved. However, if the remote join field is indexed and the table is large, Jet will often use the index to retrieve only the required rows by making multiple calls to the remote table, one fore each row required.
- Jet allows you to mix data types within [typo - fix later] of UNION queries and within expressions, but SQL server doesn't. Such mixing of data types will force processing to be done locally.
- Multiple outer joins in one query will be processed locally.
- The most important factor is reducing the total number of records being fetched. Jet will retrieve multiple batches of records in the background until the result set is complete, so even though you may seem to get results back immediately, a continuing load is being placed on the server for large result sets.

*Note: this book is quite old (published in 2000) and is in reference to Jet Engine. I imagine things might be slightly different in newer versions of Access which use ACE, although I don't have a source to back this up.*