# Access 2010 Query Syntax error

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

(1)  The Access Database is being used as way to connect to 2 Teradata databases
(2)  Currently it has 6 linked tables to 2 Teradata databases
(3)  It doesn't matter to me if it is an Access Query or a pass-through query to Teradata
(4)  The goal is to put something in an Excel macro that will query the 2 Teradata bases and return some information that will be included in a macro

I'm trying to create a SQL query in Access with SQL that works in Teradata.  When I try to run the query, I get am error message (Syntax error in FROM clause)  and the 1st Join is highlighted.  I've written queries in Access before but nothing this complex.  We are using Access 2010.  Any suggestions on the syntax error would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks for the help.......

```
select veh_mgmt_csr.cst_bo_item.veh_lgcy_nbr as unit, veh_mgmt_csr.cst_bo_item.veh_odmtr_qty as mileage, veh_mgmt_csr.rm_cust_mast.upp_lgl_cust_nam as cust_legal_name, veh_mgmt_csr_rv.cst_address.addr_st_nam as address,
veh_mgmt_csr_rv.cst_address.addr_cty_nam as city, veh_mgmt_csr_rv.cst_address.addr_postl_cde as zip, veh_mgmt_csr_rv.cst_address.stprov_cde as state, veh_mgmt_csr_rv.cst_address.cntry_iso_cde as country, veh_mgmt_csr_rv.cst_address.addr_phn_nbr as location_phone, e.contact_name, e.contact_phone
from veh_mgmt_csr.cst_buyer_order
Join veh_mgmt_csr.cst_bo_item on veh_mgmt_csr.cst_buyer_order.bo_id = veh_mgmt_csr.cst_bo_item.bo_id and veh_mgmt_csr.cst_bo_item.veh_invy_stat_dsc = 'SOLD'
Join veh_mgmt_csr.rm_cust_mast on veh_mgmt_csr.cst_buyer_order.rm_cust_id = veh_mgmt_csr.rm_cust_mast.rm_cust_id
Join VEH_MGMT_CSR_RV.cst_address on veh_mgmt_csr.rm_cust_mast.prim_addr_id = veh_mgmt_csr_rv.cst_address.addr_id and veh_mgmt_csr_rv.cst_address.record_status = 'A'
left join (select veh_mgmt_csr.cst_buyer_order.e_o_id cust_nbr,trim(veh_mgmt_csr.cst_individual.indiv_upp_frst_nam) || ' ' || trim(veh_mgmt_csr.cst_individual.indiv_upp_last_nam) contact_name,
VEH_MGMT_CSR_RV.CST_PHONE_NBR.phn_nbr contact_phone from veh_mgmt_csr.cst_e_o_cntct
left join veh_mgmt_csr.cst_individual on veh_mgmt_csr.cst_e_o_cntct.indiv_id = veh_mgmt_csr.cst_individual.indiv_id
left join  VEH_MGMT_CSR_RV.CST_PHONE_NBR on veh_mgmt_csr.cst_e_o_cntct.indiv_id = VEH_MGMT_CSR_RV.CST_PHONE_NBR.indiv_id and VEH_MGMT_CSR_RV.CST_PHONE_NBR.prim_phn_ind = 1
qualify rank() over (partition by veh_mgmt_csr.cst_e_o_cntct.e_o_id order by contact_name asc) = 1) e  on veh_mgmt_csr.rm_cust_mast.rm_cust_id = e.cust_nbr
where veh_mgmt_csr.cst_individual.veh_lgcy_nbr = '8B5RG1'
and veh_mgmt_csr.cst_e_o_cntct.cntry_iso_cde in ('US','CA')
and extract(year from veh_mgmt_csr.cst_e_o_cntct.bo_dte) = 2017
```

Comment: Your query would appear to have almost nothing in common with Access SQL.

Comment: ^^ This. Try using a **Pass-Through query** instead, it uses the SQL syntax of your database server.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Method 'Open' of object'\_Recordset' failed error message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47535126/method-open-of-object-recordset-failed-error-message)

Comment: I have never seen Extract(). Use `Year(veh_mgmt_csr.cst_e_o_cntct.bo_dte) = 2017`. Access SQL has a Partition() function but not sure it will do what you want. https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Partition-Function-1A846A33-60C7-4371-8E77-C94278274DC5. Access SQL does not have intrinsic ranking capability http://allenbrowne.com/ranking.html

Comment: @Andre...........The SQL above goes to 2 different databases.  I have a data source for each database.  How do I get that all in 1 query?  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a beginner to SQL, please note that while most RDBMS's including MS Access and Teradata may run ANSI-SQL (basic, standard DDL/DML statements), almost no two RDBMS's share the same dialects (ANSI-plus). Each maintains their own styles and specific methods.

Additionally, do note MS Access comes in two folds: 1) a GUI .exe application and 2) a database engine (ACE/JET database engine). Over time it has been conflated to be the same but they are not. See this [meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/33216) post. The former .exe application by default connects to the default database engine but this default can be switched out for other backends like Teradata.

However, the [method of connection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46963973/1422451) between frontend GUI and backend database (i.e., linked tables, pass-through queries, application code) will differ in the SQL dialect used.

1. linked tables => MS Access SQL dialect
2. pass-through queries => Backend RDBMS database dialect
3. application code (i.e., VBA) => Backend RDBMS database dialect

You may be attempting to run Teradata SQL on MS Access linked tables, hence violating #1 with resulting syntax errors. As seen below with proper indentation, there are several incompatible syntaxes in your attempted query:

1. MS Access uses only one period qualifier between table name and column name. Likely you may be referencing a named schema, only available in Teradata.
2. MS Access does not use `JOIN` by itself but requires `INNER`, `LEFT`, or `RIGHT` (no `OUTER`);
3. MS Access requires parentheses whenever pairs of tables are used in `JOIN` clauses;
4. MS Access does not support window functions such as `RANK() OVER...`;
5. MS Access uses `&` in concatenation not double pipes `||` and uses `Year()` instead of `extract(year ...)`; and does not use `qualify`, possibly strictly a Teradata method;
6. MS Access requires `AS` for column aliases such as for *contact_name* and *contact_phone*.

**SQL**

```
SELECT    veh_mgmt_csr.cst_bo_item.veh_lgcy_nbr      AS unit,
          veh_mgmt_csr.cst_bo_item.veh_odmtr_qty     AS mileage,
          veh_mgmt_csr.rm_cust_mast.upp_lgl_cust_nam AS cust_legal_name,
          veh_mgmt_csr_rv.cst_address.addr_st_nam    AS address,
          veh_mgmt_csr_rv.cst_address.addr_cty_nam   AS city,
          veh_mgmt_csr_rv.cst_address.addr_postl_cde AS zip,
          veh_mgmt_csr_rv.cst_address.stprov_cde     AS state,
          veh_mgmt_csr_rv.cst_address.cntry_iso_cde  AS country,
          veh_mgmt_csr_rv.cst_address.addr_phn_nbr   AS location_phone,
          e.contact_name,
          e.contact_phone
FROM      veh_mgmt_csr.cst_buyer_order
JOIN      veh_mgmt_csr.cst_bo_item
ON        veh_mgmt_csr.cst_buyer_order.bo_id = veh_mgmt_csr.cst_bo_item.bo_id
AND       veh_mgmt_csr.cst_bo_item.veh_invy_stat_dsc = 'SOLD'
JOIN      veh_mgmt_csr.rm_cust_mast
ON        veh_mgmt_csr.cst_buyer_order.rm_cust_id = veh_mgmt_csr.rm_cust_mast.rm_cust_id
JOIN      veh_mgmt_csr_rv.cst_address
ON        veh_mgmt_csr.rm_cust_mast.prim_addr_id = veh_mgmt_csr_rv.cst_address.addr_id
AND       veh_mgmt_csr_rv.cst_address.record_status = 'A'
LEFT JOIN
          (
           SELECT    veh_mgmt_csr.cst_buyer_order.e_o_id cust_nbr,
                     Trim(veh_mgmt_csr.cst_individual.indiv_upp_frst_nam)
                          || ' ' || 
                     Trim(veh_mgmt_csr.cst_individual.indiv_upp_last_nam) contact_name,
                     veh_mgmt_csr_rv.cst_phone_nbr.phn_nbr                contact_phone
           FROM      veh_mgmt_csr.cst_e_o_cntct
           LEFT JOIN veh_mgmt_csr.cst_individual
           ON        veh_mgmt_csr.cst_e_o_cntct.indiv_id = veh_mgmt_csr.cst_individual.indiv_id
           LEFT JOIN veh_mgmt_csr_rv.cst_phone_nbr
           ON        veh_mgmt_csr.cst_e_o_cntct.indiv_id = veh_mgmt_csr_rv.cst_phone_nbr.indiv_id
           AND       veh_mgmt_csr_rv.cst_phone_nbr.prim_phn_ind = 1 
                     qualify rank() OVER (partition BY veh_mgmt_csr.cst_e_o_cntct.e_o_id 
           ORDER BY contact_name ASC) = 1) e
ON        veh_mgmt_csr.rm_cust_mast.rm_cust_id = e.cust_nbr
WHERE     veh_mgmt_csr.cst_individual.veh_lgcy_nbr = '8B5RG1'
AND       veh_mgmt_csr.cst_e_o_cntct.cntry_iso_cde IN ('US','CA')
AND       extract(year FROM veh_mgmt_csr.cst_e_o_cntct.bo_dte) = 2017;
```

Per your update do the following:

1. To keep above Teradata syntax, create 2 pass-through queries (using same ODBC connection as linked tables) for each database.
2. Run same make-table query (`SELECT * INTO myAccessTable FROM myTeradataPassThroughQuery`) to move Teradata results into Access local tables.
3. Join the two new tables for your final end result using Access SQL syntax.

Comment: @Parfait.............Thanks for the info.  I've tried a number of different options and am probably confusing myself.  The SQL I have is for Teradata and works exactly like it should.  My first thought was to run the SQL from the Excel VBA.  I've done this before but only have to go to one database.  The SQL above goes to 2 different databases.  I have an Access database with linked tables (using 2 data sources because there are 2 databases).  I started creating a pass-through query but can only use 1 data source.  So I'm kind of stuck again.  The SQL is select only.

Comment: Please edit your post (no long comments here) with details: 1) current objective of Access app and 2) current and/or needed connections (ALL databases including RDBMS types) (e.g., linked tables to what?, two databases on same sever?, query's tables connect to what db?). Use edit link below post.

Comment: See my update per your edit. Same process of using pass-through to both dbs and then join using local tables.

Comment: @Parfait............Thanks for your help.  I have been able to get the Pass-Through query to work with the info you have provided.  Thanks again

Comment: Great to hear! Glad to help. Yes MS Access is a multi-faceted program of many parts. Leave complex queries and specialized syntax to backend engines and use Access for user interfacing and reporting.